# Are there freely available texts of Geseriad in English?

Tags: translation, source-request

I was trying to do some research of Geseriad (aka [Epic of King Gesar/Kesar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_King_Gesar)) details (for [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140147/in-universe-is-gesar-the-same-person-as-the-central-asian-folk-hero)), but while I found a couple of academic references, some even re-telling many parts of the epos, I wasn't able to find freely available text (in English telling or translation) of ANY version of Geseriad, Tibetian or Mongolian or Chinese.

Is there one that escaped my notice?

I'm fine if it's a very close re-telling, and not literal translation, e.g. like "The Superhuman Life of Gesar of Ling" By Alexandra David-Neel.

Comment: From the wikipedia page you link (and in particular the section "History of Gesar studies") it's not entirely clear to me that there even exists an english translation (free or not) of the Mongolian texts. They do however link (in the section "external links") to [this translation](https://web.archive.org/web/20070629041814/www.buryatmongol.com/halaa1.html) (via waybackmachine) of the Buryat version.

Comment: @plannapus - the one I mentioned (Neel) is, I think, of Tibetian version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find this [one](http://buryatmongol.org/epic-of-king-gesar-translation-by-sarangerel-odigon-2/), certainly not the best, but a good one, and as free as you like.